# Why isn't my genymotion device listed when I run "adb devices"

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion, nativescript

I am starting my first android project using nativescript.

I want to run my project with genymotion.

In genymotion GUI settings/ADB I am using custom Android SDK tools and genymotion tells me the android SDK tools are found. Also the VirtualBox path is valid, and when I renamed the device the VirtualBox name and Genymotion name both changed. The Virtualbox VM is powered down.

I start genymotion and get the emulator open with a black screen. I then run:

```
tns run android
```

per the [nativescript docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-1)

I get as output:

```
Cannot find connected devices. Reconnect any connected devices, verify that your system recognizes them, and run this command again.
```

I then tried running:

```
adb devices
```

and got an empty list so it seems my device is not being recognized, I just don't know why.

I have also tried running:

```
tns run android --emulator --geny nameOfDevice
```

This starts the emulator but again just a blank screen. So I guess nativescript knows about the device but adb doesnt?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and apologies in advance if I am missing some obvious android issue.

Comment: try adb kill-server

Comment: then adb start-server

Comment: @HabibKazemi - I did so and ran adb devices again. The server restarted with same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not open genymotion before adb initialisation.

Start adb server first 
by `adb start-server`
and then open genymotion to initialise emulator.

After that you should be able to see emulator in list of running devices through adb command. I ran into the same scenario where adb does not list emulators if genymotion is opened before adb initialisation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thats it! Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 5):

You should also make sure that your GenyMotion is using the right SDK.

Go to: >> **Settings** >> **ADB**
And choose **Use custom Android SDK Tools**

If the SDk path is found it will be marked with

***Android SDK Tools successfully found!***

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to respond. I did try this... As I mentioned in the question: "I am using custom Android SDK tools and genymotion tells me the android SDK tools are found" :)

Answer (score 0):

My working solution is:

```sh
cd /opt/genymobile/genymotion/tools
./adb devices
```

You have to use its own **adb** tool.